# Title the appendices

Tags: appendices

I would like to give a title ("Complements") to an appendix : initially, I thought to title using `\section` by removing the numbering (using `\section*{Complements}`) but for the following subtitles ( `\subsection{Title 1}`) the numbering is not correct (.1 instead of A.1)

So I was wondering if there was a way to give an appendix a title?

So I was wondering if there was a way to give an appendix a title?

thank you in advance

````
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} 
\usepackage[french]{babel}
\usepackage[left=1.5cm, right=1.5cm, top=1.5cm, bottom=1.5cm]{geometry}

\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{enumitem}  %pour l'option [resume] qui permet de reprendre la numérotation
\usepackage{pifont}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{tabulary}
\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}
\usepackage{verbatim}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{appendix}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{picinpar}

\usepackage[european, RPvoltages, straightvoltages]{circuitikz}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{titlesec}

\hypersetup{colorlinks=false, linkcolor=black}
\usetikzlibrary{babel}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\newenvironment{manip}{\begin{itemize}[label=\ding{45}]}{\end{itemize}}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\newcolumntype{Y}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}X} 
\titleformat{\section}[hang]{\LARGE \bfseries}{\Roman{section}}{1em}{}
\titlespacing*{\section}{0pt}{*5}{*0.5}
\titleformat{\subsection}[hang]{\Large \bfseries}{\Roman{section}.\arabic{subsection}}{1em}{}
\titlespacing*{\subsection}{0pt}{*4}{*0.5}
\titleformat{\subsubsection}[hang]{\large \bfseries}{\Roman{section}.\arabic{subsection}.\alph{subsubsection}}{1em}{}
\titlespacing*{\subsubsection}{0pt}{*3}{*0.5}
\titleformat{\paragraph}[hang]{\normalsize \bfseries}{\theparagraph}{0em}{}
\titlespacing*{\paragraph}{0pt}{*3}{*0.5}


\begin{document}
\section{Titre}
\subsection{SOus-titre}
\subsection{sous-titre}
\section{Titre}
\subsection{SOus-titre}
\subsection{sous-titre}

\appendix
\clearpage
\renewcommand{\thesubsection}{\Alph{subsection}}
\renewcommand{\thesubsubsection}{\Alph{subsection}.\arabic{subsubsection}}
\section*{Compléments} %title of the appendice
\subsection{Titre}
\subsection{Titre}
\end{document}```
````

Comment: Normally, in the article class each appendix should be a section.

Comment: in fact I have only one annex with subtitles

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The \appendix command resets the section number to 0. You define the `\titleformat` for `\subsection` with `\Roman{section`, which will be empty for section number 0. So you should redefine it for the appendices to use the new subsection number format.

```
\renewcommand{\thesubsection}{\Alph{subsection}}
\renewcommand{\thesubsubsection}{\thesubsection.\arabic{subsubsection}}
\titleformat{\subsection}[hang]{\Large \bfseries}{\thesubsection}{1em}{}
```

Comment: thanks, it works

Answer (score 0):

I see you use the `appendix` package. Try

```
\usepackage[page]{appendix} % put a title in the document
\renewcommand{\appendixpagename}{Complements}
...
\begin{appendices}
\section{Title}
\section{Title}
\subsection{Subtitle}
\end{appendices}
```

Read the `appendix` package manual for more information. (I have a feeling that the `appendices` environment does not necessarily work well with `titlesec` changes to divisional commands.)